# Java object definition shorthand or shortcuts?

Tags: java, eclipse, guava, diamond-operator

Is there a faster way to instantiate objects in Java where one does not have to retype the class?  For example, look at this tome of an instantiation:

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<ActivityRecord>> days = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<ActivityRecord>>();
```

I'd love a shorthand that was along the lines of:

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<ActivityRecord>> days = new();
```

Alternately, I'd also be happy with an Eclipse shortcut that auto-completed the instantiation to use the no-parameter constructor.

Comment: Often you will declare the variable type to be an `interface` type, but instantiate it with a real class, e.g. `Map<Integer, List<ActivityRecord>>  = new HashMap<>();`. So the right side of the equality _needs_ to have the class being instantiated.

Comment: @pbabcdefp Indeed, updated my comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using Java 7 and above you can use the [diamond operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html#diamond):

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<ActivityRecord>> days = new HashMap<>();
```

Also, when declaring your variables it is good practice to use the interfaces when possible, instead of the concrete classes. So the above would really be:

```
Map<Integer, List<ActivityRecord>> days = new HashMap<>();
```

If you are using Java 6, you can do this using [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava):

```
Map<Integer, List<ActivityRecord>> days = Maps.newHashMap();
```

For further reading, you can check the section on **Type Inference and Instantiation of Generic Classes** in the [Type Inference documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html).

Comment: Love the Google Guava tip!  (I have to keep it in J6, so this works well)

Answer (score 2):

You should the Java 7 [diamond operator](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074080/core-java/jdk-7--the-diamond-operator.html) because often you'll be coding to the interface and not using the same class for the reference and the instance.

```
Map<Integer, ArrayList<ActivityRecord>> days = new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Java 6 (or earlier) then Google Guava comes in handy

```
Map<Integer, List<ActivityRecord>> days = Maps.newHashMap();
```